# d3js v5 + Topojson v3 Map not rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I don't know why, according to the topojson version (may be) I have:

> TypeError: t is undefined

An explanation could be nice! (I use the last version of topojson.)

**Here an example of TypeError is undefined** (pointing to topojson file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.0.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


  <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>

  <script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

    var unemployment = d3.map();

    var path = d3.geoPath();

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1, 10])
        .rangeRound([600, 860]);

    var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
        .domain(d3.range(2, 10))
        .range(d3.schemeBlues[9]);

    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "key")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,40)");

    g.selectAll("rect")
      .data(color.range().map(function(d) {
          d = color.invertExtent(d);
          if (d[0] == null) d[0] = x.domain()[0];
          if (d[1] == null) d[1] = x.domain()[1];
          return d;
        }))
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("height", 8)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d[1]) - x(d[0]); })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d[0]); });

    g.append("text")
        .attr("class", "caption")
        .attr("x", x.range()[0])
        .attr("y", -6)
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .text("Unemployment rate");

    g.call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .tickSize(13)
        .tickFormat(function(x, i) { return i ? x : x + "%"; })
        .tickValues(color.domain()))
      .select(".domain")
        .remove();




    var files = ["https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", "unemployment.tsv"];
    var promises1 = d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json");
    var promises2 = d3.tsv("unemployment.tsv");



    Promise.all([promises1, promises2]).then(function(us){
        console.log(us[0]);
        console.log(us[1]);


      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "counties")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us[0].objects.counties).features)
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate = unemployment.get(d.id)); })
          .attr("d", path)
        .append("title")
          .text(function(d) { return d.rate + "%"; });

      svg.append("path")
          .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us[0].objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
          .attr("class", "states")
          .attr("d", path);
      });

  </script>



  </body>

</html>
```

My code : https://plnkr.co/edit/EzcZMSEQVzCt4uoYCLIc?p=info

Original (d3js v4 + Topojson v2) : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606

**Here an another example of TypeError is undefined** (pointing to topojson file)

My code : https://plnkr.co/edit/o1wQX3tvIDVxEbDtdVZP?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two examples have two separate issues in relation to topojson.

In the first example you update where the topojson is held from `us` to `us[0]` due to the change in how files are fetched. However, you haven't quite updated the code to reflect this change:

In Original: `.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)`

In Question: `.data(topojson.feature(us, us[0].objects.counties).features)`

And fixed: `.data(topojson.feature(us[0], us[0].objects.counties).features)`

Updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/STLzvbc7EdTyBFG8VfzK?p=preview).

---

However, the issue in the second example is a little different.

`topojson.feature` requires two parameters, a topology and an object. The topology is the variable holding the json, which you have correct. However, the object is not `arcs`. The variable holding the topojson has a property called objects, and in that there will always be at least one property representing a feature collection (states, counties, etc). This object (or one of these objects) is what we want.

Here is a snippet of your topojson:

`... "objects":{"dep_GEN_WGS84_UTF8":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"arcs ..."`

We want `topojson.feature(data,data.objects.dep_GEN_WGS84_UTF8)`.

If making topojson with tools such as mapshaper, the object we want to display is the same as the name of the file used to create it. Generally, a quick word search through the topojson for "object" will also get you to the proper object pretty quick.

The arcs property in a topojson is convenient storage for the pieces that make up the features, not the features themselves.

Updated [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ihndc79pHuMatJkYZlg?p=preview).

---

In both cases the topology parameter passed to `topojson.feature` won't contain the specified features, generating the same error.